# How to execute Ember.RSVP.all within an ember run loop correctly

Tags: ember.js, rsvp.js

I'm trying to execute a promise inside Ember.RSVP.all

```
App.Foo = Ember.Object.create({
    bar: function() {
        var configuration = ajaxPromise("/api/configuration/", "GET");
        Ember.RSVP.all([configuration]).then(function(response) {
            //do something with the response in here
        });
    }
});
```

But because my integration test mocks the xhr w/out a run loop the test fails with the expected error "You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop' autorun"

So I wrapped the RSVP with a simple ember.run like so

```
App.Foo = Ember.Object.create({
    bar: function() {
        var configuration = ajaxPromise("/api/configuration/", "GET");
        Ember.run(function() {
            Ember.RSVP.all([configuration]).then(function(response) {
                //do something with the response in here
            });
        });
    }
});
```

But I still get the error for some odd reason. Note -if I run later it's fine (this won't work though as I need to exec the async code for this test to work correctly)

```
App.Foo = Ember.Object.create({
    bar: function() {
        var configuration = ajaxPromise("/api/configuration/", "GET");
        Ember.run.later(function() {
            Ember.RSVP.all([configuration]).then(function(response) {
                //do something with the response in here
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my ajaxPromise implementation -fyi

```
var ajaxPromise = function(url, type, hash) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        hash = hash || {};
        hash.url = url;
        hash.type = type;
        hash.dataType = 'json';

        hash.success = function(json) {
            Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
        };

        hash.error = function(json) {
            Ember.run(null, reject, json);
        };

        $.ajax(hash);
    });
}
```

How can I wrap the Ember.RVSP inside my ember run w/out it throwing this error?

**Update**

here is my test setup (including my helper)

```
document.write('<div id="ember-testing-container"><div id="wrap"></div></div>');
App.setupForTesting();
App.injectTestHelpers();

test("test this async stuff works", function() {
    visit("/").then(function() {
        equal(1, 1, "omg");
    });
});
```

The only part I've left out is that I'm using jquery-mockjax so no run loop wraps the xhr mock (and in part that's why I like this library, it fails a test when I don't wrap async code with a run loop as the core team suggests)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may have to do with how your tests are being run, so if you can provide the test, it will be helpful

I also noticed:

It turns out I believe you are also being (or will be soon) trolled by jQuery's jQXHR object being a malformed promise, the fulfills with itself for 0 reason, and enforcing its own nextTurn on you. Which is causing the autorun. This will only happen in the error scenario.

In ember data we sort this out, by stripping the `then` off the jQXHR object

see: 
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/4bca3d7e86043c7c5c4a854052a99dc2b4089be7/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L539-L541

I suspect the following will clear this up.

```
var ajaxPromise = function(url, type, hash) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        hash = hash || {};
        hash.url = url;
        hash.type = type;
        hash.dataType = 'json';

        hash.success = function(json) {
            Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
        };

        hash.error = function(json) {
            if (json && json.then) { json.then = null } // this line

            Ember.run(null, reject, json);
        };

        $.ajax(hash);
    });
}
```

This is rather unfortunate, and various separate concepts and ideas are coming together to cause you pain.  We hope to (very shortly) land `Ember.ajax` which normalizes all these crazy away.

Also feel free to checkout how ember-data is going this: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/4bca3d7e86043c7c5c4a854052a99dc2b4089be7/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L570-L586

Comment: I've updated the above -let me give your suggestion a run quick

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain on this Toran, I'm sure it's what Stefan's stated, we had to 1 off mockjax to get our tests to work with it.

https://github.com/kingpin2k/jquery-mockjax/commit/ccd8df8ed7f64672f35490752b95e527c09931b5

```
    // jQuery < 1.4 doesn't have onreadystate change for xhr
      if ($.isFunction(onReady)) {
        if (mockHandler.isTimeout) {
          this.status = -1;
        }
        Em.run(function () {
          onReady.call(self, mockHandler.isTimeout ? 'timeout' : undefined);
        });
      } else if (mockHandler.isTimeout) {
        // Fix for 1.3.2 timeout to keep success from firing.
        this.status = -1;
      }
```

Comment: don't you miss that added benefit I mention above (where I want my tests to fail when i'm doing async stuff w/out a run-loop) ?

Comment: ya, you likley don't wont to do this. Anyways shortly Ember.ajax will wrap this up nicely, and peoples pain should go away.

Comment: Toran, it wraps the code path of the response in the run loop, essentially the same thing as wrapping the response/reject methods in the run loop. Stefan, yeah, we  know it's a band-aid fix while we've been migrating all of our tests over from jasmine to qunit and building integration tests.

Comment: We actually were lazily waiting on ryan florence's feature to get pulled/rejected before we changed anything

Comment: tho now that I look at it I see he just started the ball.